# Ruby - OAuth 2.0 JWT Bearer Token Flow

Tags: oauth2, jwt, ruby

I am following [this document](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=remoteaccess_oauth_jwt_flow.htm) as I try to implement the Salesforce OAuth 2.0 JWT Bearer Token Flow. There are a number of steps involved and I have tried them over and over again but I keep getting `{"error"=>"invalid_grant", "error_description"=>"invalid assertion"}`.

I hope someone can point out to me what I may have missed. Here is my code:

```
require "httparty"
class Salesforce
  def initialize
    @cert_file = File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), *%w[private_key.pem])
    @base_url = "https://xxxxx--yyyy.zzzz.my.salesforce.com"
    @auth_endpoint = "/services/oauth2/authorize"
    @token_request_endpoint = "/services/oauth2/token"
    @token_revoke_endpoint = "/services/oauth2/revoke"
    @username = "user@mail.com"
    @client_id = "client_id"
    @private_key = OpenSSL::PKey::RSA.new(File.read(@cert_file))
  end

  # Construct a JWT header with this format: {"alg":"RS256"}.
  # Base64url encode the JWT header

  def encoded_jwt_header
    Base64.strict_encode64({"alg":"RS256"}.to_s)
  end

  # Construct a JSON Claims Set for the JWT with iss, sub, aud, and exp.

  def claim_set
    {
      iss: @client_id, 
      sub: @username, 
      aud: @base_url,
      exp: (Time.now + 3.minutes).to_i.to_s
    }
  end

  # Base64url encode the JWT Claims Set without any line breaks.

  def encoded_claim_set
    Base64.strict_encode64(claim_set.to_s)
  end

  # Create a string for the encoded JWT Header and the encoded JWT Claims Set

  def claim_set_header_combo
    "#{encoded_jwt_header}.#{encoded_claim_set}"
  end

  # Sign the resulting string using SHA256 with RSA

  def signed_claim_set_header_combo
    # From the docs, it is not very clear if I should sign with the private key or not
    # Digest::SHA256.base64digest(claim_set_header_combo) 
    JWT.encode(claim_set_header_combo, @private_key, 'RS256')
  end

  def jwt_bearer_token
    "#{claim_set_header_combo}.#{Base64.strict_encode64(signed_claim_set_header_combo)}"
  end

  def request_auth
    HTTParty.post("#{@base_url}#{@token_request_endpoint}", body: {grant_type: "urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer", assertion: jwt_bearer_token}, debug_output: $stdout)
  end
end
```

**EDIT**

I have revised the code to make use of the `ruby-jwt` gem:

```
require "httparty"
class Salesforce
  def initialize
    @cert_file = File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), *%w[private_key.pem])
    @base_url = "https://test.salesforce.com"
    @auth_endpoint = "/services/oauth2/authorize"
    @token_request_endpoint = "/services/oauth2/token"
    @token_revoke_endpoint = "/services/oauth2/revoke"
    @username = "hsisis-xzc5@force.com"
    @client_id = "client_id" 
    @private_key = OpenSSL::PKey::RSA.new(File.read(@cert_file))
  end

  def claim_set
    {
      iss: @client_id, 
      sub: @username, 
      aud: @base_url,
      exp: (Time.now + 3.minutes).to_i.to_s
    }
  end

  def jwt_bearer_token
    JWT.encode(claim_set.to_s, @private_key, 'RS256')
  end

  def request_auth
    HTTParty.post("#{@base_url}#{@token_request_endpoint}", body: {grant_type: "urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer", assertion: jwt_bearer_token}, debug_output: $stdout)
  end
end
```

Am not familiar with Salesforce and am developing this for a client so am not sure if I maybe missing something. Any ideas that will point me in the right direction will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Don't reinvent the wheel - there are plenty of Ruby gems (libraries) available for construction of JWT, [ruby-jwt](https://github.com/jwt/ruby-jwt) being the most popular.
2. The `aud`(ience) claim AND the endpoint (`base_url` in your code) need to be `https://login.salesforce.com` (Production), `https://test.salesforce.com` (Sandbox) or a community URL.  This is covered in the [docs](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=remoteaccess_oauth_jwt_flow.htm&type=5).

To test on your own, you can [sign up for your own free Developer Edition org](https://developer.salesforce.com/signup), create a connected app (see docs above + [tutorial](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/connected-app-basics)) and go from there.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I have created a dev account, created an app and made the changes you mentioned. Am still getting `invalid assertion`. My certs are `.pem` files? Does that matter?

Comment: .pem is fine. If the cert format was an issue, it'd complain. Post your revised code.

Comment: I have updated my question with the revised code. Please take a look.

Answer (score 0):

I've only a passing familiarity with Ruby, but...

```
def signed_claim_set_header_combo
  # From the docs, it is not very clear if I should sign with the private key or not
  # Digest::SHA256.base64digest(claim_set_header_combo) 
  JWT.encode(claim_set_header_combo, @private_key, 'RS256')
end
```

Yep, you need to sign the JWT with your private key. You also need to make sure that the certificate itself is being used by the *Connected App* that you set up on the Salesforce end of things. I forget if you do that from editing the Connected App itself, or through managing the policies for the Connected App, but dig around for a bit and you should find a *Use Digital Signature* checkbox. That needs to be checked, and that'll allow you to upload the .crt file for your cert.

The other bit that I see is wrong is your Base64 encoding. Since the signed JWT is sent in the url query string for your auth request, it needs to be url safe. There is a variant of Base64 called Base64URL, which replaces 2 url-unsafe characters with safe replacements (<kbd>+</kbd> and <kbd>/</kbd> are replaced with <kbd>-</kbd> and <kbd>_</kbd>, respectively).

Use `Base64.urlsafe_encode64` instead of `Base64.strict_encode64`

If you're still running into issues after that, then perhaps try changing the base url that you're sending the auth request to to "https://login.salesforce.com" (for production) or "https://test.salesforce.com" (for a sandbox).

Comment: Thanks for chiming in on this. I was given the base URL in this format: `https://xxxxx--yyyy.zzzz.my.salesforce.com`. Can this work? I saw "https://login.salesforce.com" and "https://test.salesforce.com" in the docs too but wasn't sure.

Comment: Also, my certs are `.pem` files. Does that make a difference?

Comment: @Muaad Re Q1: Perhaps, but I'm not certain. The docs mention being able to use a community url, but the one you were given is a "myDomain" url. The safe approach would be to use the login or test endpoint. When you get a successful response, it'll contain an `instance_url` (which might match your given `x-y-z.my.salesforce.com` url) that you can rely on for making subesquent requests to Salesforce. Re Q2: Yes, I believe the Connected App on the Salesforce side only accepts .crt files

Comment: OK. This is still failing. I don't have access to the connected app so I will have to ask them these questions tomorrow. I will update once I get more info. Thanks for the help.