# {"error":"invalid_grant","error_description":"invalid assertion"} I want to send post request to Salesforce

Tags: jwt, ruby, ruby-on-rails

I am trying to send post request to salesforce for Oauth by using JWT and I wrote it like the one below, but I got an error that says `{"error":"invalid_grant","error_description":"invalid assertion"}`
and I don't know how to fix it because I think I included everything I needed.
If anyone know what I am wrong about please tell me.

```
 require 'jwt'
    require 'json'
    require 'net/http'
    require 'uri'
    require 'active_support/all'
    
    class Salesforce
      def initialize
        @cert_file = File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), *%w[private-key.pem])
        @base_url = "https://login.salesforce.com"
        @auth_endpoint = "/services/oauth2/authorize"
        @token_request_endpoint = "/services/oauth2/token"
        @token_revoke_endpoint = "/services/oauth2/revoke"
        @username = "My email
        @client_id = "My consumer key"
        @private_key = OpenSSL::PKey::RSA.new(File.read(@cert_file))
      end
    
    
      def claim_set
        {
          iss: @client_id,
          sub: @username,
          aud: @base_url,
          exp: (Time.now + 3.minutes).to_i.to_s
        }
      end
    
      def jwt_bearer_token
        JWT.encode(self.claim_set.to_s, @private_key, 'RS256')
      end
    
      def request_auth
        post = {grant_type: "urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer", assertion: jwt_bearer_token}
        uri = URI.parse("#{@base_url}#{@token_request_endpoint}")
        https = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, 443)
        https.use_ssl = true
        response = https.post(uri.path, post.to_query)
        print response.body
      end
    
      print Salesforce.new.request_auth
      print Salesforce.new.jwt_bearer_token
    
    end
```

**UPDATE**

when I checked my JWT with debugger in JWT.io, I found out the payload looks this, which is created in a line and has this (backslash)

```
"{:iss=>\"3asojnbosbnfobgsooQFZasfjbnsodZXgO2bCyJriuKHsdfadKI\", :sub=>\"aben@example\", :aud=>\"https://login.salesforce.com\", :exp=>\"1624588836\"}"
```

reference:
https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.remoteaccess_oauth_jwt_flow.htm&type=5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am sure you would have come across https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/quickstart_oauth.htm which has the grant_type required on header.

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.remoteaccess_oauth_username_password_flow.htm&type=5

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12794302/salesforce-authentication-failing

Let me know if it helps!